# Why Laravel ORM Eloquent not saving the correct values?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, one-to-many

I'm working in a special relationship with laravel where I have articles and compatible articles. One article could have many compatible articles and, at the same time a compatible article has its parent as compatible.

Article A is compatible with B, so B is compatible with A.

To achieve this I created a One to Many relationship where I have two tables:

articles and compatibles

The columns of `articles` are:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->string('code', 20)->unique();
```

While `compatibles` table columns are:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('primary_id');
$table->string('primary_code', 20);
$table->unsignedBigInteger('secondary_id');
$table->string('secondary_code', 20);
```

To create an article I need to save the data two times, on right and inverse way, thus, assigning a compatible to an article, that article is assigned as compatible of the first one:

```
$articulo = Articulo::findOrFail($request->get('id'));

foreach ($data['compatibles'] as $value) {

    $secundario = Article::select('id')->where('code',trim($value['compatible']))->first();

    $secondary_id = $secondary->id;
    $primary_id   = $article->id;

    $article->compatibles()->createMany([
            [
                'primary_id'       => $primary_id,
                'primary_code'     => trim($value['codigo']),
                'secondary_id'     => $secondary_id,
                'secondary_code'   => trim($value['compatible']),
            ],

            // inverse
            [
                'primary_id'       => $secondary_id, // secondary_id on primary_id place, but insert sentence doesn't respect this.
                'primary_code'     => trim($value['compatible']),
                'secondary_id'     => $primary_id, // primary_id at secondary_id place
                'secondary_code'   => trim($value['code']),
            ]
        ]
    );

}
```

The first registry is perfectly saved but its inverse repeats the `primary_id` instead saving the secondary_id in its place.

If I do `print_r` to debug, the arrays shows correctly, but for some reaseon that I can't figure out it doesn't insert same data.

Just in case, I paste my Models

```
class Compatible extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'stock';
    protected $fillable = ['primary_id', 'primary_code', 'secondary_id', 'secondary_code'];

    public function article()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
    }
}
```

```
class Article extends Model
{
    public function compatibles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Compatible', 'primary_id');
    }
}
```

I have to say that all this process is excuted within a DB transaction. I'm relatively new with Laravel and I don't know if that would be interfering on something.

Comment: Please check the queries which is executed during insertions. for this put `DB::enableQueryLog()` in top of the function and at the end `print_r(DB::getQueryLog())` . the query log will give an idea

Comment: An M:N relationship seems to model your use case a little better, but that's just me.

Comment: Please, tell me more @IGP, what do you mean with M:N relationship?

Comment: Many to many relationship. An Article has and belongs to many compatible Articles, does it not?